# dnsmasq not running

Tags: 12.04, network-manager, dnsmasq

i installed ubuntu 12.04 on a netbook with 16GB SSD. To keep the installation small i used the mini.iso i got from [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD).

Everything worked fine, but i noticed that dnsmasq does not get started by NetworkManager. On a different machine i installed 12.04 from a regular iso and netstat shows dnsmasq running and listening on port 53.

NetworkManager.conf look identically on both systems. The line **dns=dnsmasq** is present.

Although i do not really need dnsmasq - name resolution works fine without - i would like to know the reason why dnsmasq is running on one system, but does not run on the other and how i could adjust this behavior.

Thx in advance!

Comment: what if you reinstall it?

Comment: @jasmines installed it in a vm. same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Were you running BIND named or standalone dnsmasq (from the dnsmasq package)? In Ubuntu 12.04 these nameservers conflicted with the NetworkManager-controlled dnsmasq instance: if one had already started then the other could not start.

In Ubuntu 12.10 they no longer conflict.